# Obtain information from web-based interactive map using R

Tags: r, dictionary, web, hyperlink, interactive

I want to write up R codes to retrieve basic information through this link below.
http://www.ewg.org/interactive-maps/2016_north_carolina_animal_feeding_operations.php

Basically, this link allows people to observe all the industrialized farms in North Carolina. After you open the web and click on a random place mark, you can see some detailed information about this specific farm. This is my first goal. I want to run R to automatically click on each dots and record the detailed information accordingly. 
After you click on the dot and see the farm information, you can then click the button "see Aerial photo". Then you can observe the webpage address in which you can find the geographical location of this farm. This would be my second objective for which I want to record the webpage address of the aerial photo.

http://www.ewg.org/interactive-maps/2016_north_carolina_animal_feeding_operations_aerial.php?lat=36.1058&long=-80.8064&zoom=17

To be honest, I have these ideas to retrieve detailed information about the farms, but I have no idea how to do the codes in R.

If anyone knows something about getting info from web or interactive map online, I hope you can share some experience with me.

Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've never done this and it looks like a challenge so good luck! I could at least recommend looking into `curl()`. I know you can scrape web text with it. Not sure how or if it would be applicable for an interactive map.

Comment: This seems very doable with ```rvest```. There are many online examples. It's a web-scraping package for R, and combined with SelectorGadget, these two tools make R web scraping very easy for someone who has never done it before.